# Close Gtk.Window modal in Genie

Tags: gtk, gtk3, genie

I'm not sure what is the best way to close a modal window (this is a Gtk.Window defined as window.set_modal (true) and not a Gtk.Dialog).

I want to use a button in the window connected to a function with Gtk.WIndow.destroy (), but it does not work well.

I read that you should use "delete-event" but I do not know how to implement it. Does anyone have an example in Genie? Thank you.

Comment: You say it does not work very well to `Gtk.Window.destroy()`. What does that mean? What do you expect to see?

Comment: Actually, it did not work out well, but now I can not say what the error was because I changed the Gtk.Window by Gtk.Dialog, and now it works fine for me.

I tried to rescue the copy of the code that returned error, but it does not find it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I have often tried to destroy a GtkWindow myself. Most times the problem is referencing/dereferencing. And in a lot of cases you want to show the window again or similar.This is where a GtkDialog works better just like you discovered. Good luck on your project.

Comment: Exactly, I think my problem was referencing. It is a mistake I make too often. Really with Gtk.Dialog I have been better. Thank you.